# how to access jquery assigned image on code behind in asp.net (c#)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

i downloaded admin template from google, i use `FileUpload` control to load images.

template uses plugin to load image at run time and image is visible to user at loading

but when user select `image` from any location then `image` is visible into `img` control but i can't see it at my `aspx` page i think `jquery` assign image on selection

below is image description:

`div` that i have on my `aspx` page

```
<div id="divImages" runat="server" type="image" class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;" >
                 </div>
```

and when i press `Shift+Ctrl+i` to `inspect elements` then i got this `div` as

```
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_divImages" type="image" class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 10px;">
<img src="here is image source......" style="max-height: 150px;"> // I need this image control id at code behind in asp.net
</div>
```

in `jquery` the line i think which works for this is

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
          preview.html('<img src="' + e.target.result + '" ' + (preview.css('max-height') != 'none' ? 'style="max-height: ' + preview.css('max-height') + ';"' : '') + ' />')
          element.addClass('fileupload-exists').removeClass('fileupload-new')
        }
```

I need this `runtime` image control to access at server side so that i need to apply some checks on this control...

i am weak in `jquery` so i need your help.

if any body does not understand this please feel free to ask, I am here to hear you..

i am using asp.net c#

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want the "uploaded" image or just the preview image back on the server-side?
If its an upload then the file uploader itself should post the file with the PostBack request. But if its the preview image url, then you might need to add the e.target.result into a hidden input field and initiate a PostBack yourself. Alternatively, you could use an ajax request and use a Page Method (ScriptMethod) to receive the URL from the Ajax request.

Comment: it is very helpful, i got your point "file uploader itself should post the file with the post back" , actually i manage my issue this way. thanks for your time and suggestion,